# asp.net webforms - facebook server side authentication on a page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm struggling for about 2 days with authenticating a user from the server side.
Using asp.net 4, c# web forms and starting to use the C# SDK, building an app for page tab.
I need to authenticate a user with the Oauth diag.
If I use `Response.Redirect`, I get a blank screen on the tab.
according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/
I need to send a JS command in order to change window.top.location but how do I do this?

my login url:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=482264391791260&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/null/153715871344670/?sk=app_482264391791260&response_type=code&display=popup&scope=email
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to send a JS command in order to change window.top.location but how do I do this?

The section entitled **2a. Redirect to OAuth Dialog upon page load** on the very same page you mentioned has an example of doing exactly that …

So what exactly is your problem in getting it done?

Comment: I assumed that using the page load will be a bit of an overload on the system since most of the time the user will enter he will already be authenticated. On server side, I want to parse the signed_request and only if the user is did not allow the app, to show the Oauth diag. This means I can't use the onload function

Comment: You don’t have to use onload. Server-side, just decide, is the user already logged in/connected, or not. If not, you just answer the request with a very basic HTML document, that contains only the JavaScript code required to redirect the user to the login dialog.

Comment: Nice :) didn't think about it.
Thanks